# UIButton cannot be clicked in UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uibutton, uitableview

I have a problem with a custom UITableViewCell,

This custom cell contains 2 UITextFields and an UIButton. In my TableViewController class I fill the cells with my content and this works.

But I want to get different actions, when clicking on a cell and clicking on the UIButton within the cell. When I click on the cell, I continue with another view, this works fine, but when I press on the button it is the same reaction, which I don't want.

I already created an IBAction of the Button within my custom Cell class, to react on clicking events, but when I click on a button, it isn't called, but the cell is selected (which I don't want). I already tried different solutions, like using target or gesture recognizer, but I didn't get it working. Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: I suppose you've already check it but anyway: is the button user interaction enabled?

Comment: @PabloLerma yes, user interaction is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. ADD 2 buttons instead of adding one button in the cell
2. Set the smaller button to the top of the smaller button .

Assuming (larger button - the cell touch portion action you want)(smaller button - the button which you have given tap action)

Comment: don't really understand your solution, do you mean, that I should place a button as big as the cell, and a small button which is placed within the large button and which I can click on? Thanks for your help!

Comment: yes, you need to place one button as big as the cell , and another button on top of it .

Comment: @Moritz Please be active when you ask one question and got response .

Comment: it worked for me, thank you!!! I was searching for a solution for hours, I still don't understand why my solution didn't work, on previous application it worked for me, don't know why I need to add 2 buttons to be able to differ between an cell and an button click, but it works for me now. Thank you!!! :)

Comment: if you add any button in cell and set target to it .then it would not call the tableview didselect row at index path as it has been overwritten by button action in cell .